# Apache - Rewrite URL

Tags: html, regex, apache, get, url-rewriting

I have a simple form in html

```
<form class="form-search" method="get" action="search.php">
  <input name="what" type="text" class="input-xlarge search-query" placeholder="what">
  <input name="where" type="text" class="input-xlarge search-query" placeholder="where">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary search">search</button>
</form>
```

When I click the button the URL is like http://example.com/search.php?what=foo&where=bar, everything fine so far.

I want the same functionality but I want to rewrite the URL to http://example.com/foo/bar/

Is it possible to achieve it with apache rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to match against the request in order to make the browser load the `/foo/bar/` URL, then internally rewrite it *back* to the query string:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} GET\ /+search\.php\?what=([^&]+)&where=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /search.php?what=$1&where=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this should work

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /search.php?what=$1&where=$2 [L]
```

with this url http://example.com/foo/bar/
if there isn't a folder named foo and a file or directory that matches the file name it 'll redirect show the request http://example.com/search.php?what=foo&where=bar result.

Answer (score 0):

http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php?page=1 has good instructions for exactly what you want to do.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)/([^/])+ /search.php?what=$1&where=$2 [NC]
```

should do the trick.